# :hover css box-shadow display error on jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am animating a div using jQuery. Like so:

```
$('#Reporting').animate({ width: 250, fontSize: 21 }, 750)
```

Then I have a box shadow on this with css

```
box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.5em 0.05em $Black;
```

However as soon as the animate kicks in the `box-shadow` is removed has anyone any idea as to why this happens? this is also removed from the `:hover` alternate `box-shadow` as well.

Thanks Tim

Comment: Could you make a fiddle

Comment: I couldn't seem to replicate the behavior http://jsfiddle.net/z7s795zh/. We need more info. Create a fiddle displaying the problem.

Comment: I am just going to give @AlanMorton2.0 answer a go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `.animate()` in jQuery is adding `overflow:hidden` to your css and so the box-shadow even though is being applied is then hidden by the inline css that jQuery has added.

Try adding this to your jQuery

```
$('#Reporting').css({ 'overflow': 'visible' });
```

This will stop jQuery auto adding the ‘hidden’ to your css and set it to visible, this should also fix the `:hover` as well.

This should fix your box-shadow issue, quite a common issue with `.animate()`

Thanks Alan